# SVN authentication via --username with single ssh user

Tags: svn, ssh

Is SVN via *svn+ssh://* able to handle **ONE** ssh- but multiple svn-users? Example:

```
svn co svn+ssh://svn@myserver.com/repo --username=userA
svn co svn+ssh://svn@myserver.com/repo --username=userB
```

Unfortunately this way doesn't seem to work. My intention is to not have a single account for every svn user. Is this possible / does this make sense?